# Calculate a point from latitude and longitude with a distance

Tags: java, gps, latitude-longitude

I am trying to calculate a point from a latitude and longitude location and a distance and bearing, but I am mixing up my maths, and probably messing up the units. Is there anybody who can help? This is my code:

```
public static double[] distFromPointWithDistance(float lat1Deg, float lng1Deg, float d, float brngDeg) {
    double lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1Deg);
    double lng1 = Math.toRadians(lng1Deg);
    double brng = Math.toRadians(brngDeg);

    double R = 6371; //kilometers
    double lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
            Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
    double lng2 = lng1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1),
            Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));

    double[] result = new double[2];
    result[0] = lat2;
    result[1] = lng2;
    return result;
}
```

For lat1Deg: 41.884344
For lng1Deg: 12.479627
For dist: 1
For brngDeg: 90.

What I would expect is 41°53′04″N, 012°29′30″E, but I get something completely different, lat2 = 0.73101. Any pointers are appreciated!

[edit]:
I added the conversion, but still get very strange results

Comment: Convert all angles from degrees to radians before using them in trig functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first glance your formulae look correct.

Java's trigonometric functions are in **radians**, not degrees as you as assuming.

To convert from degrees to radians, multiply by `Pi / 180`.

Comment: I added this: double lat1 = lat1Deg * Math.PI / 180;
double lng1 = lng1Deg * Math.PI / 180;
double brng = brngDeg * Math.PI / 180; That should do it shouldn't it?